# Automatically Detect Facebook Activity

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am an experienced WordPress developer but sadly I have very little experience with Facebook SDK's.

What I am wondering is if it is possible to create code that will detect whenever a user likes a post/page, "unlikes" a post/page, shares a post/page and logs in to the website via Facebook.

I know that if the like, share and login buttons are coded by myself that I can get a response from the events. However I am wanting to add code to my achievements/points plugin that would detect the events from code that is created by someone else, such as a plugin or the website owner so that it can award the user with points/achievements.

I have tried using the "FB.Event.subscribe" event in the JS SDK to hook into events but this has so far been unsuccessful.

P.S. I don't expect a full tutorial or "cut & paste" code, I am simply wondering if it is possible or if I am wasting my time. Any helpful links and/or offers to help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not allowed to reward users for using Facebook’s social channels – please read the Platform Policies.

Comment: Hello, Please can you provide information on where in the policies it states that you cannot reward users for liking a post/page. Thank You.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration

Comment: Thank You for the fast reply.